# How to replace an attribute as well as its content with a new one?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I have an html marked by the class `link-right verbtable` in which I would like to replace the attribute `href` as well as its value, i.e.

`href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer"`

with a new one

`old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();" data-text = "+"`.

One way to do it is to read this html as string and use function `replace`. Because this content is from an html, I would like to ask for a method that use `BeautifulSoup`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a class="link-right verbtable" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer">Full verb table</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I hope i have understand your question... You have an answer @LAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to replace `href=` of all selected `<a>` tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
    <a class="link-right verbtable" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer">Full verb table</a>
    <a class="link-right verbtable" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer">Full verb table</a>
    <a class="link-right verbtable" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer">Full verb table</a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a.link-right.verbtable'):
    del a['href']
    a['old_onclick'] = 'expandfullverbtable();'
    a['onclick'] = 'expandfullverbtable();'
    a['data-text'] = '+'

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a>
<a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a>
<a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a>
```

Comment: This also solves the case where there are multiples replacement. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
remove = ['href']
new =['old_onclick', 'onclick', 'data-text']
values = ['expandfullverbtable();', 'expandfullverbtable();', '"+"']
html = '''
    <a class="link-right verbtable" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer">Full verb table</a>
    <a class="link-right verbtable" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer">Full verb table</a>
    <a class="link-right verbtable" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer">Full verb table</a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.select('a.link-right.verbtable'):
    for n, v in zip(new, values):
        a[n] = v
    a.attrs = {key:value for key,value in a.attrs.items()
               if key not in remove}
print(soup)
```

prints:

```
<a class="link-right verbtable" data-text='"+"' old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a>
<a class="link-right verbtable" data-text='"+"' old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a>
<a class="link-right verbtable" data-text='"+"' old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a>
```

Comment: The content marked by the class `link-right verbtable` appears several times, whereas your code use `.select_one`. Could you please modify it to do the replacement for all such instances?